# how to access an id from one class in another class

Tags: python, kivy

i want to access an id from class main to class fahim2_pop. want to access to word from textinput(in main class) to the popup widget which will appear when someone press the search button. when someone search "hello" and press search button the the popup widget will appear and in that popup widget the text of the label will be "hello" same as from the textinput. but the label and the id remains in different class. how to do it?

python code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import *

class fahim2_pop(Popup):
    pass

class main(BoxLayout):  
    def word(self):
        pop=fahim2_pop()
        pop.open()

class go(BoxLayout):
    def main(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(main())

class CallApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return go()

CallApp().run()
```

kv code

```
Builder.load_string('''

<main>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        TextInput:
            id:word
        Button:
            text:"search"
            on_press:root.word()

<go>:
    Button:
        text:"go"
        on_press:root.go()

<fahim2_pop>:
    id:pop
    title:"result"
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text:app.root.ids.word.text 

''')
```

i know app.root.ids.word.text if that id remain in root of my app. but here go is the root of app. how to access id from class main in class fahim2_pop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of solving this problem. One of the solution is as follow:

### py file

- Rename method `main()` in class `go()` to `go()` because in your kv file, you have binded `on_press: root.go()`
- Instantiate `main()` and store it in a class attribute, `main`

#### Snippets - py file

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
...

class go(BoxLayout):
    main = ObjectProperty(None)    # declare class attribute

    def go(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.main = main()
        self.add_widget(self.main)
```

### kv file

- Replace `text:app.root.ids.word.text` with `text:app.root.main.ids.word.text`

#### Snippets - kv file

```
<fahim2_pop>:
    ...
        Label:
            text:app.root.main.ids.word.text
```

## Example - main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Builder.load_string('''

<main>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        TextInput:
            id:word
        Button:
            text:"search"
            on_press:root.word()

<go>:
    Button:
        text:"go"
        on_press:root.go()

<fahim2_pop>:
    id:pop
    title:"result"
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text:app.root.main.ids.word.text 

''')


class fahim2_pop(Popup):
    pass


class main(BoxLayout):
    def word(self):
        pop = fahim2_pop()
        pop.open()


class go(BoxLayout):
    main = ObjectProperty(None)

    def go(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.main = main()
        self.add_widget(self.main)


class CallApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return go()


CallApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: App started]
[image: TextInput]
[image: Popup]

Comment: its showing an error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'ids'

Comment: Try running the example that is in my updated post.

Comment: here go is the root of my app. if the hierarchy is go>main>class "x"> popup. the how can i access an id from class "x" to that popup widget?  i think its something like instantiating that class x in class main. but then how to access that id in popup widget, if here i cant use app.root cause main is not the root

Comment: 1) Declare a class attribute, `x` (just like `main`) in class `main()`. 2) Instantiate class `x()` and save it, `self.x = x()`.  3) Add `x` in the reference e.g. `app.root.main.x.ids.word.text`

Comment: just awesome! great man great! i wasted so many time solving this problem!